# Appending multiple svg text with d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have been stuck on this problem for days.

So I have a dataset of objects of the following form:

```
dataset = [{metric:"revenue",value:0.03},{metric:"sales", value:0.15},{metric:"churn", value: 0.06},{metric:"logins", value: 0.45}]
```

The following code would display the 4 metric names in a grid pattern (meshy, meshx are the coordinates points of the grid and meshsize is the size of the grid, so this is just putting the text in the middle of a grid square):

```
svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d){
        return d.metric;
    })
    .attr("y",function(d,i){
        return meshy[i] + meshsize/2;
    })
    .attr("x", function(d,i){
        return meshx[i] + meshsize/2;
    })
    .attr("font-size",25)
    .attr("font-family","serif")
    .attr("text-anchor","middle")
    .attr("font-weight","bold");
```

Now I would like to put the value of the metric right underneath the metric name like so:

```
 svg.append("text")
    .data(dataset)
    .text(function(d){
        return (d.value);
    })
    .attr("y",function(d,i){
        return meshy[i] + meshsize/2 + 20;
    })
    .attr("x", function(d,i){
        return meshx[i] + meshsize/2 ;
    })
    .attr("font-size",25)
    .attr("font-family","serif")
    .attr("text-anchor","middle")
    .attr("font-weight","bold");
```

But this only returns the value underneath the metric name for the FIRST metric, the other 3 value texts are not even in the DOM. I have tried multiple approaches including replacing .text with .html as described here:https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-html with no success. I have also tried appending paragraph elements instead - this works but the p elements are positioned below the svg body in a list with no obvious way to move them into the right position. The code above is the closest I have come to getting what I need, but for some reason only the first value text shows up. However, I am open to any approach in d3 that gets the job done: 4 metric names with the values right underneath them

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In your second block of code, you are only appending one `text` element, hence only one of them is appearing. What you need to do is to append the text similar to your first block, i.e. with the `.enter()` selection. For this, you have two choices. You can either save and reuse the `.enter()` selection, or assign different classes to the two kinds of text to be able to distinguish between them.

Option 1:

```
var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter();

texts.append("text")
     .text(function(d){
                    return d.metric;
                })
     // set position etc.

texts.append("text")
     .text(function(d){
                    return d.value;
                })
     // set position etc.
```

Option 2:

```
svg.selectAll("text.title")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("text")
                .attr("class", "title")
                .text(function(d){
                    return d.metric;
                })
     // set position etc.

svg.selectAll("text.value")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("text")
                .attr("class", "value")
                .text(function(d){
                    return d.value;
                })
     // set position etc.
```

The first option is obviously shorter, but depending on what else you want to do, the second option may be preferable -- if you want to modify the text afterwards, it will be a lot easier if you can distinguish between the two kinds of text. You can also use the different classes to give different CSS styles.